# Fresh Ubuntu installation with full disk encryption fails on dell XPS 13 9380 with 22.04 or 22.10 out of memory

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, encryption, xps

I had Ubuntu running on the xps for years without problems.
Then suddenly after an update it did not boot and halted with an error 'out of memory' before the luks password input.

I tried to fix it and finally decided to do a fresh install with full disk encryption. It turns out it is still not booting after fresh installation with full disk encryption option (standard installation boots flawlessly).

Any ideas? Am I the only one with that problem?

[Image boot recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Lsq.jpg)

[Image boot normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaxzw.png)

Comment: Sounds similar to the existing issue with U22.04 LTS right now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-unsigned/+bug/1842320

Comment: I found this one, too. But I am not sure if this is the root cause, because it boots without luks.